# Writing a script task to run my Python application within Bamboo

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, deployment, bamboo

I want to run my Python application (through Bamboo) using a Script task which runs the application.
I tried (as a task) with

> `Python myprogram.py`

But it blocks the process of deployment and its `status` remains `InProgress`.
How to run the Python application from within Bamboo (deployment phase) successfully ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with the way you are trying to run your python script from within your deployment. Can you confirm that you are not using inline with script task to run your python script ? Also the other thing, have you run your python script locally, just to be sure there is no issue within your code ?